# Automatically copy items

Tags: 2010, javascript, document-library, copy-and-paste

We have 6 different libraries. All of them are working with a checkbox column (management). Is it possible to run a script or something like that, which grabs all documents (management = yes) and copy those into another library? Or show them in one list to open it with the explorer view?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be using Event Receivers. That, though, requires developing a custom component. Here is a simple [HOW-TO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx)

What you need is an ItemAdded event receiver, which would check the value of Management column and if it's true, the document would be copied to a different library. You can handle ItemUpdated event as well, if someone decides to change Management No to Management Yes.

Other way to do it would be a Ribbon button which would open up an application page. On that page you can use a caml query to get items from all your 6 libraries or use an SPSiteDataQuery if the number of libraries might change in the future. Examples [Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8168/how-to-query-multiple-document-libraries) and [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/401818/SharePoint-SPSiteDataQuery-with-Example)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

@paul-strupeikis has the correct answer here IMHO, but I would like to point out a straight forward alternative (albeit not as pretty):

Consider using PowerShell in a Scheduled Task.
It depends on how instant you need the transferring to occur, but if you could let it wait 2-5 minutes then this approach could be a good enough solution for you.
We find ourselves using this approach often, as I find it easier to get an overview of all the "batch jobs", and it's easier to maintain/change (can be a bad thing).

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/eirikb/78df4e220782e7f9d9df) for a starter template.